# fetching float values from jformatted text field

Tags: java, swing, types, jformattedtextfield

I am able to create JFormatted TextField that accepts only float values,but I am not able to fetch that value....
I am declaring it ..

```
stopAppFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("#.00"));
```

and fetching the value using :

```
double stop=(Double)stopAppFormattedTextField.getValue();
```

but the above statement is throwing the following exception:

> "Exception in thread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double"

what should I do to fetch float values?
-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting `Long`s from the formatter, but you want  `double`s. You can do this:

```
Number number = (Number)stopAppFormattedTextField.getValue();
double stop = number.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your code after initialization:

```
stopAppFormattedTextField.setValue(0d);
```

The getValue will return double auto-magically